# In Opencl clGetDeviceIDs return error CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY

Tags: c, linux, arm, opencl, mali

I have [firefly rk 3288 board](http://en.t-firefly.com/en/firenow/firefly_rk3288/specifications/) with GPU and so I want test openCL C code , Written very basic code which can read platform info as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <CL/cl.h>
#define LOGI  printf

int main() {

    cl_uint i_plat;
    cl_int err;

    // Discover the number of platforms:
    cl_uint nplatforms;
    err = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &nplatforms);

    LOGI("\n Number of Platform %d: error = %d ", nplatforms, err );

    //check_error(err, "clGetPlatformIds");
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    // Now ask OpenCL for the platform IDs:
    cl_platform_id* platforms = (cl_platform_id*)malloc(sizeof(cl_platform_id)* nplatforms);


    if(platforms == NULL){
        printf("\n Fail to allocate memory for platforms");
    }


    err = clGetPlatformIDs(nplatforms, platforms, NULL);
    LOGI("\n clGetPlatformIDs return error = %d ", err );

    //check_error(err, "clGetPlatformIds");

    // Ask OpenCL about each platform to understand the problem:
    char name[128];
    char vendor[128];
    char version[128];
    char driver[128];
    cl_uint val = 0;
    size_t val1 = 0;
    size_t val2 = 0;
    size_t prof_tmr_res = 0;
    cl_uint MaxComputeUnit = 0;
    cl_uint MaxClockFrequency = 0;

    cl_device_type deviceType;

    cl_device_exec_capabilities exec_capabilities;

    //LOGI(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"POOJA","AKVEDIAHE");

    for (i_plat = 0; i_plat < nplatforms; i_plat++) {
        err |= clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[i_plat], CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR, 128, vendor, NULL);
        err |= clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[i_plat], CL_PLATFORM_NAME, 128, name, NULL);
        err |= clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[i_plat], CL_PLATFORM_VERSION, 128, version, NULL);
        //check_error(err, "clGetPlatformInfo");

        LOGI("\n Platform Info %d: Vendor = %s Name = %s Version = %s  Error = %d", i_plat, vendor, name, version,err);

        /*device info*/
        //err = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[i_plat], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, &ret_num_devices);
        err = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[i_plat], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);

        LOGI("\n clGetDeviceIDs GPU  Error %d ",err );

        err |= clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE,sizeof(cl_int), &deviceType, NULL);
        err |= clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_VENDOR, 128, vendor, NULL);
        err |= clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_NAME, 128, name, NULL);
        err |= clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_VERSION, 128, version, NULL);
        err |= clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DRIVER_VERSION, 128, driver, NULL);
        err |= clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS, sizeof(cl_uint), &val, NULL);
        err |= clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_PROFILING_TIMER_RESOLUTION, sizeof(size_t), &prof_tmr_res, NULL);
        err |= clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS, sizeof(cl_uint), &MaxComputeUnit, NULL);
        err |= clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY, sizeof(cl_uint), &MaxClockFrequency, NULL);
        err |= clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_EXECUTION_CAPABILITIES,sizeof(cl_int), &exec_capabilities, NULL);

        LOGI("\n Device Type %08x:",deviceType );
        for(int i =0; i < val ; i++){
            err = clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES, sizeof(size_t), &val1, NULL);
            LOGI("\n MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES[%d] = %d,", i,val1 );
        }
        err = clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, sizeof(size_t), &val2, NULL);

        LOGI("\n MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS = %d , MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE = %d ", val,val2 );
        LOGI("\n device_id FOR Platform = %d vender = %s, device name = %s, device version = %s, driver version = %s", i_plat, vendor, name, version, driver);
        LOGI("\n CL_DEVICE_PROFILING_TIMER_RESOLUTION = %d",prof_tmr_res );
        LOGI("\n Max Compute Unit = %d",MaxComputeUnit );
        LOGI("\n Max Clock Frequency = %d",MaxClockFrequency );
        LOGI("\n Device exec capabilities = %08x",exec_capabilities );
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

**Output :**

> Number of Platform 1: error = 0
>
> clGetPlatformIDs return error = 0
>
> Platform Info 0: Vendor = ARM Name = ARM Platform Version = OpenCL 1.1
>   Error = 0
>
> clGetDeviceIDs GPU  Error -6
>
> Device Type ffffffdf:
>
> MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS = 0 , MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE = 0
>
> device_id FOR Platform = 0 vender = ARM, device name = ARM Platform,
>
> device version = OpenCL 1.1 , driver version = �*��
>
> CL_DEVICE_PROFILING_TIMER_RESOLUTION = 0
>
> Max Compute Unit = 0
>
> Max Clock Frequency = 0

Now not understanding Why it's returns `-6 (CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY)` ?

Why it's failing to allocate resources required by the OpenCL implementation on the host or where I missing ?

Comment: I looked into your code and OpenCL doc. I see no problem with what you have done. I'd contact firefly tech support if I were you.

Comment: try :  `err = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[i_plat], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id, NULL);`

Comment: @pradyot is correct. ret_num_devices is not defined, therefore you are asking for a big and unknown amount of device IDs.

Comment: I have passed `NULL` in `clGetDeviceIDs` as last argument but still it's not working having same error.

Comment: `clGetDeviceInfo` is not working correctly because, here we need to pass `device_id` and which i don't have. Output for Device Type is 00001029.

Comment: @Mohan can you please share your clinfo. Feel free to add it in your question as edit.

Comment: I have added my complete code...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115686/discussion-between-pradyot-and-mohan).

Answer (score 0):

I use OpenCL in my app on RK3288 (Android, Viewsonic VSD242), and I have no problem with below code.
I hope this code helps someone.

```
cl_context OPENCL_CONTEXT;
cl_command_queue OPENCL_COMMAND_QUEUE;
cl_kernel* OPENCL_KERNELS;
cl_device_id OPENCL_DEVICE_ID;
cl_program OPENCL_PROGRAM;
cl_uint OPENCL_NUM_KERNELS;


void init_openCL() {

  size_t kernel_code_size;
  cl_int ret;
  cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
  cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
  cl_uint ret_num_devices;
  char buildLog[1024];
  int i;

  ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
  print_opencl_result("clGetPlatformIDs", ret);
  LOGD("--->available number of platforms = %d", ret_num_platforms);
  ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &OPENCL_DEVICE_ID, &ret_num_devices);
  print_opencl_result("clGetDeviceIDs", ret);
  LOGD("--->available number of devices = %d", ret_num_devices);
  OPENCL_CONTEXT = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &OPENCL_DEVICE_ID, NULL, NULL, &ret);
  print_opencl_result("clCreateContext", ret);
  //OPENCL_COMMAND_QUEUE = clCreateCommandQueue(OPENCL_CONTEXT, OPENCL_DEVICE_ID, 0, &ret);
  OPENCL_COMMAND_QUEUE = clCreateCommandQueue(OPENCL_CONTEXT, OPENCL_DEVICE_ID, CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE, &ret);
  print_opencl_result("clCreateCommandQueue", ret);


  // load kernel code from the assets directory
  const char* source = (const char*)loadResourceFromAssets("my_kernels.cl");
  kernel_code_size = sizeof(source);


  OPENCL_PROGRAM = clCreateProgramWithSource(OPENCL_CONTEXT, 1, &source, NULL, &ret);
  print_opencl_result("clCreateProgramWithSource", ret);
  ret = clBuildProgram(OPENCL_PROGRAM, 1, &OPENCL_DEVICE_ID, "", NULL, NULL);
  print_opencl_result("clBuildProgram", ret);

  ret = clGetProgramBuildInfo(OPENCL_PROGRAM, OPENCL_DEVICE_ID, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 1024, buildLog, NULL);
  print_opencl_result("clGetProgramBuildInfo", ret);
  LOGD("%s", buildLog);

  ret = clCreateKernelsInProgram(OPENCL_PROGRAM, 0, NULL, &OPENCL_NUM_KERNELS);
  OPENCL_KERNELS = (cl_kernel*)malloc(OPENCL_NUM_KERNELS * sizeof(cl_kernel));
  ret = clCreateKernelsInProgram(OPENCL_PROGRAM, OPENCL_NUM_KERNELS, OPENCL_KERNELS, NULL);
  print_opencl_result("clCreateKernelsInProgram", ret);

}



void close_openCL() {
  int i;

  clFinish(OPENCL_COMMAND_QUEUE);
  clReleaseContext(OPENCL_CONTEXT);
  clReleaseCommandQueue(OPENCL_COMMAND_QUEUE);

  for (i = 0; i < OPENCL_NUM_KERNELS; i++) {
    clReleaseKernel(OPENCL_KERNELS[i]);
  }
  clReleaseProgram(OPENCL_PROGRAM);
  free(OPENCL_KERNELS);
}


void print_opencl_result(const char *name, int ret) {
  if (ret == CL_SUCCESS) {
      print_logD("--->%s = success", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_COMPILER_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_COMPILER_NOT_AVAILABLE", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_PROFILING_INFO_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_PROFILING_INFO_NOT_AVAILABLE", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_MEM_COPY_OVERLAP) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_MEM_COPY_OVERLAP", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_IMAGE_FORMAT_MISMATCH) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_IMAGE_FORMAT_MISMATCH", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_IMAGE_FORMAT_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_IMAGE_FORMAT_NOT_SUPPORTED", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_BUILD_PROGRAM_FAILURE", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_MAP_FAILURE) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_MAP_FAILURE", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_MISALIGNED_SUB_BUFFER_OFFSET) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_MISALIGNED_SUB_BUFFER_OFFSET", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_EXEC_STATUS_ERROR_FOR_EVENTS_IN_WAIT_LIST) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_EXEC_STATUS_ERROR_FOR_EVENTS_IN_WAIT_LIST", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_VALUE) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_VALUE", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_DEVICE_TYPE) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_DEVICE_TYPE", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_PLATFORM) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_PLATFORM", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_DEVICE) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_DEVICE", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_CONTEXT) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_CONTEXT", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_QUEUE_PROPERTIES) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_QUEUE_PROPERTIES", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_HOST_PTR) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_HOST_PTR", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTOR) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTOR", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_IMAGE_SIZE) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_IMAGE_SIZE", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_SAMPLER) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_SAMPLER", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_BINARY) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_BINARY", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_BUILD_OPTIONS) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_BUILD_OPTIONS", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_PROGRAM) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_PROGRAM", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_KERNEL_NAME", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_KERNEL_DEFINITION) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_KERNEL_DEFINITION", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_KERNEL) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_KERNEL", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_ARG_INDEX) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_ARG_INDEX", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_ARG_VALUE) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_ARG_VALUE", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_ARG_SIZE", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_WORK_DIMENSION) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_WORK_DIMENSION", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_WORK_ITEM_SIZE) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_WORK_ITEM_SIZE", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_OFFSET) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_OFFSET", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_EVENT_WAIT_LIST) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_EVENT_WAIT_LIST", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_EVENT) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_EVENT", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_OPERATION) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_OPERATION", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_GL_OBJECT) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_GL_OBJECT", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_BUFFER_SIZE) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_BUFFER_SIZE", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_MIP_LEVEL) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_MIP_LEVEL", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE", name);
  } else if (ret == CL_INVALID_PROPERTY) {
      print_logE("--->%s = CL_INVALID_PROPERTY", name);
  } else {
      print_logE("--->%s is failed", name);
  }
}
```